# AWS S3 : TransferUtility dose not contain the definition for UploadAsync in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3, awss3transferutility

While using following code getting the error

> TransferUtility does not contain the definition for UploadAsync

---

```
TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);

TransferUtilityUploadRequest uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
{
    BucketName = "bucketname",
    FilePath = "foldername",
    Key = "filename",
    InputStream = "file input Stream"
};

uploadRequest.UploadProgressEvent +=
    new EventHandler<UploadProgressArgs>(uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent);

await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution, I was using AWSSDK.S3 of version 3.3.102.9 and .Net of version 4.0

To use `UploadAsync()` It's required AWSSDK.S3 of 3.3.102.11 version and it's requires .Net version 4.5 or above.